# Google Chrome theme color for href links hover

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, manifest, google-chrome-theme

I'm creating a theme for Chrome, but when I set `"tab_text"` in manifest.json, the bottom URL status bar is the same color. I searched for a solution in the documentation, but I didn't find an attribute that tints the bottom bar. It affects that bar (as seen on picture) and the download list too. Is there a way to customize the bottom URL status bar?

```
"colors" : {
    "tab_text" : [150,150,150]
}
```

[image: The <code>"tab_text"</code> affects the bottom bar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had a look at the source file for this (linked from [the Chrome theme page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/themes.html#colors) on Google code). There currently is no way of setting the status bar text independently.

The background color of the status bar is always the same as that of the toolbar.

Comment: I accept this as answer. I searched for solution a lot. There is no solution at this time.

Comment: @Tamschi, They fixed this yet?

Answer (score 1):

While it's not possible to do it today, there is a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94009) raised for this in the Chromium issue tracker, if you want to star it.